# How can I allow Devise users to log in when they're outside my default scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, warden, default-scope

I have a Rails 4 app which uses Devise 3.4 for authentication, which I've customized with the ability to ban users (using a simple boolean column `users.banned`, default false). The `User` model also has a `default_scope` which only returns non-banned users.

Here's the problem - I still want my banned users to be able to *log in*, even though they can't do anything after logging in. (They essentially just see a page saying "you've been banned"). But it seems that the `default_scope` is tripping up Devise. When you log in or call e.g. `authenticate_user!`, Devise tries to find the current user using one of the basic ActiveRecord methods like `find` or `find_by`, but can't because they lie outside the default scope. Thus Devise concludes that the user doesn't exist, and the login fails.

How can I make Devise ignore the default scope?

Answer (score 4):

After a **long** time digging around in the Devise and Warden source code, I finally found a solution.

#### Short Answer:

Add this to the `User` class:

```
def self.serialize_from_session(key, salt)
  record = to_adapter.klass.unscoped.find(key[0])
  record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
end
```

(Note that I've only tested this for ActiveRecord; if you're using a different ORM adapter you probably need to change the first line of the method... but then I'm not sure if other ORM adapters even have the concept of a "default so

#### Long Answer:

`serialize_from_session` is mixed into the User class from -[`Devise::Models::Authenticatable::ClassMethods`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Authenticatable/ClassMethods). Honestly, I'm not sure what it's actually supposed to do, but it's a public method and documented (very sparsely) in the Devise API, so I don't think there's much chance of it being removed from Devise without warning.

Here's the original source code as of Devise 3.4.1:

```
def serialize_from_session(key, salt)
  record = to_adapter.get(key)
  record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
end
```

The problem lies with `to_adapter.get(key)`. `to_adapter` returns an instance of `OrmAdapter::ActiveRecord` wrapped around the `User` class, and `to_adapter.get` is essentially the same as calling `User.find`. (Devise uses the `orm_adapter` gem to keep it flexible; the above method will work without modification whether you're using ActiveRecord, Mongoid or any other OrmAdapter-compatible ORM.)

But, of course, `User.find` only searches within the default_scope, which is why it can't find my banned users. Calling `to_adapter.klass` returns the `User` class directly, and from then I can call `unscoped.find` to search **all** my users and make the banned ones visible to Devise. So the working line is:

```
record = to_adapter.klass.unscoped.find(key[0])
```

Note that I'm passing `key[0]` instead of `key`, because `key` is an Array (in this case with one element) and passing an Array to `find` will return an Array, which isn't what we want.

Also note that calling `klass` within the real Devise source code would be a bad idea, as it means you lose the advantages of `OrmAdapter`. But within your own app, where you know with certainty which ORM you're using (something Devise doesn't know), it's safe to be specific.